# How to read/write custom properties in Excel Online & PowerPoint online using Office.js?

Tags: office-js

We are developing Office Add-in for online office apps.
Looking for API to read/write custom properties in Excel and PowerPoint online.

For Word online it can be achieved using following:

```
function setProperties() {
console.log("Adding custom properties ...");
Word.run(function (context) {
context.document.properties.customProperties.add("TestOBID", "WTDoc:1234");
return context.sync()
.catch(function (e) {
console.log(e.message);
})
})
}

function getProperties() {
console.log("Reading custom properties ...");
Word.run(function (context) {
var customDocProps = context.document.properties.customProperties;
context.load(customDocProps);
return context.sync()
.then(function () {
console.log("No. of custom properties:: " + customDocProps.items.length);
})
})
}
```

What are APIs for Excel and PowerPoint online ?
It would be helpful if you provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs for Excel are [Excel.CustomProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel_release/excel.customproperty?view=office-js) and [Excel.CustomPropertyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel_release/excel.custompropertycollection?view=office-js).

Comment: is Office.Document.CustomXmlParts expected to work for PowerPoint? It's always null when I try to access it from a PowerPoint context (works from Word)

Comment: My bad. CustomXmlParts are supported only on Word. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/office-add-in-requirement-sets#customxmlparts. I have removed that reference from my answer.